# VBA to highlight "sets" of rows according to incrementing field values

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, highlight

I have a long chuck of code that successfully creates a large set of data.

The final task (CODE NOT WRITTEN) is to highlight all populated cols (A:BD) the same color, and for that color to change each time an identifier (in col B) changes. Each ID can have from 1-10 rows associated with it.

I need the colors to be pastel (so you can still read black text).

I am fine hardcoding a set of RGB in the code (maybe 10 colors), and just having the highlight loop through those colors in succession.

what I am trying to get to in psuedo:

```
c1 = RGB(R, G, B)
c2 = RGB(R, G, B)
c3 = RGB(R, G, B)
c4 = RGB(R, G, B)
c5 = RGB(R, G, B)

Sheet1.Range("A1:BD1").Interior.Color = c1

if b2=b1 Sheet1.Range("A2:BD2").Interior.Color = c1
   else Sheet1.Range("A2:BD2").Interior.Color = c2

if b3=b2 Sheet1.Range("A2:BD2").Interior.Color = c2
   else Sheet1.Range("A2:BD2").Interior.Color = c3
```

Comment: You haven't shown us any of your code, so it's not clear exactly what the question is here. If you can edit to add code and explain exactly what specific problem(s) you ran into, likely someone can help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is my first post, sorry if it was not clear. At this point, i do not have anything to debug, I was hoping for some help in putting it together. VBA is not my normal language. I have tried to edit the post, but happy to provide more, for sure.

Comment: Store your colors in an array of RGB values (or use a worksheet range and fill the cells in the range with the colors your want).  Loop over the rows and each time the ColB value changes increment a counter which you can use as an index into the array/range to get the next color.

Comment: Tim, thank you so much for taking the time to reply, appreciate you. I was able to re-open my question. Is there a more appropriate spot here to post this to get some help on the syntax. I realize this may be trivial task to most, but I am not sure how to do what you suggest (having the RGB go back to color 1 when you reach the last color, etc). I am not trying to be lazy. Thanks for any advice you might provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub ColorRows()
    Dim rngColors As Range, rw As Range, i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngToColor As Range, numColors As Long, clr As Long
    
    'setting the background color of each cell in this range...
    Set rngColors = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("A1:A10") 'for example
    numColors = rngColors.Cells.Count 'how many colors
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some specific worksheet
    Set rngToColor = ws.Range("A2:BD" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row)
    
    i = 1
    clr = rngColors(i).Interior.Color 'starting color
    For Each rw In rngToColor.Rows
        rw.Interior.Color = clr
        'value in B in next row is different?
        If rw.Cells(2).Value <> rw.Cells(2).Offset(1).Value Then
            i = i + 1
            If i > numColors Then i = 1 'loop back to the start?
            clr = rngColors(i).Interior.Color 'next color
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: It's ABSOLUTELY PERFECT! Exactly what I was hoping for.... amazing (to me) work, thank you for all of your time Tim